# How many non-partisan (independent) legislature members in the USA compared to the USSR?

Tags: united-states, parties, soviet-union

How many legislature members who are not members of any party in the USA compared to the USSR?

Comment: What are you expecting to understand from this comparison?

Comment: Not really sure its a useful measure. Number of political parties would be more helpful, but even that's not really helpful. The US political structure forces some very disparate groups (such as Libertarians and Conservative Evangelicals) into the same party.

Comment: I think most would agree that the spread of political opinion in the US is less wide than it is in (say) Europe. But I don't think the number of independent legislators is related to that. The number of political parties represented in the legislature might be a better measure.

Comment: @DJClayworth By *spread of political opinion*, do you mean opinions among the population, or among politicians in office?

Comment: @gerrit Politicians in office

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/113th_United_States_Congress) indicates that there are currently two members of the Senate who are neither Republican or Democrat, and zero members of the House of Representatives. As far as I can tell neither is a member of any party.

For most of its life only communist candidates were elected to the various soviets of the USSR.

Comment: Can you somehow support your claim that only Communist candidates were elected in the USSR? Russian Wikipedia tells that in the Supreme Council of the USSR of 1937 below 1/5 of the members were non-partisan, in the Supreme Council of 1970 54% of the members were independent.

Comment: [English Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_democracy#Elections_in_the_USSR) (admittedly without reference) that until 1989 candidates were selected by the local Communist party. That doesn't necessarily mean that all candidates were members of it. If you have additional information I'm happy to edit my answer (though I can't read Russian).

Comment: Can I also mention that if you knew the figures for the USSR, that would have been helpful information to include in the question.

Comment: This link to a booklet printed in 1980 for foreigners visiting the USSR for the Olympics in Moscow http://www.situation.ru/app/rs/lib/ussr100/ussr1006.htm#hdr_13 informs that into the Councils in 1980 were elected 2274699 deputies, of which there were 979805 members of the Communist party, or 43,1 percent. But I want an independent answer.

Comment: Doesn't sound like either of us have really reliable information.

Comment: Bernie Sanders is a Socialist. Though I'm not sure how official that is as far as party membership, since he's listed as "independent"

Comment: I have found no mention of any party affiliation for him. He does caucus with the Democrats.

Comment: @Anixx to claim there were any "non-partisan" representatives anywhere in power in 1937 is beyond laughable. 1937 is a year where the repressive campaign - the Great Purge - was at its peak - anybody who was suspected in diverging from the party line or even associating with "enemies of the people" was imprisoned for extended terms or executed. Whatever formal associations were there, anybody in any official capacity was but the most loyal person to communists, otherwise he'd quickly find himself before the troika (or, as it usually were, convicted in absentia by the same troika).

Comment: @Anixx you seem to misunderstand how USSR political system worked. The only permitted party of course was the communist party. However, not everybody was deemed good enough to join. So, when elections were held there was what is called "a block of communists and independents" (блок коммунистов и беспартийных) which was the only choice in these "elections". Of course, the candidates were pre-approved under the close guidance of the party and the government (another cliche - it's always "the decision of the party and the government" and you never needed to say which party is it).

Comment: @StasM You compare a 1980s document to 1937. This is not an appropriate thing to do.

Comment: @jjack 1937 indeed was different from 1980s, but not in this regard. The first real party has been created in 1988 ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Union_(Russia) )  - before that, there were no independent parties. And before 1985, the year where Gorbachev's reforms started, there was no such possibility at all. First elections deserving this name happened in 1989. So technically it's true that "1980s" were different, if you count 1989, but certainly 1980 wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

In the Soviet Union elections (up until the Perestroika) there were only two options:

1. Communists and non-partisans, running as a single block ("блок коммунистов и беспартийных")
2. Against all

So there wasn't any real competition between members of the Communist party and other candidates. Each district only had one candidate pre-selected by the ruling party and voting "against all" was challenging because it required you to openly cross out the candidate's name, instead of simply placing your ballot in the ballot box. This means that essentially the word "non-partisan" is meaningless when it comes to the Soviet parliament.

Now, one might attempt to argue that the American Congress is similar to the Soviet system as 99% of its members belong to one or two of the ruling parties. However the biggest difference is that the central party committees in Washington don't hold complete control over the selection of candidates, as evidenced by the recent [special election in Alabama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Senate_special_election_in_Alabama,_2017). An even bigger example is the election of Donald Trump to Presidency, as he wasn't endorsed by many of the Republican leaders. The comparison you're trying to make is misguided, even though I agree that the American system deserves a lot of criticism.

Comment: Hey you don't know anything about how the comparison might be guided. Unless you're trying to whup something out of him.